# Use a variable as a task input

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a PowerShell task that detects whether there are any `.npmrc` files that use the AzureDevOps feed and therefore need authenticating.

```ps
...
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=npmrcForAuth]$npmrc"
```

I use this to conditionally run the task.

The `condition` works, but how do you pass the same value to the `workingFile` input?

```yaml
- task: npmAuthenticate@0
  condition: ne(variables['npmrcForAuth'], '') # this works
  displayName: "Authenticate with Azure DevOps NPM"
  inputs:
    workingFile: "variables['npmrcForAuth']" # this doesn't work. Nor does ${{ variables['npmrcForAuth'] }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
workingFile: "$(npmrcForAuth)"
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash)

Comment: That seems to have done it, ta. I'd never have guessed that.